# An Olympiad problem in prime numbers :can we proof that "n" is prime in this case "

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let x,n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$
 such that :

1+$x^1$+$x^2$+$x^3$+....+$x^{n-1}$ is prime .

Proof that n is prime .

I actually suppose that n isn't prime absurdly so n=p×k such as p is prime ,I also use the $a^n$-$b^n$ formula  and find that $x^k$-1/$x^1$-1 so that means that k=1 and then 
n=p which is absurd.
Does Anyone has another answer ?

Comment: How do you get from $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$ is prime to $k=1$?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885159/when-is-xn-1-x-1-a-prime-number).

Comment: I meant $x^k$-1 devise x-1 that means that there's a d∈N such as x-1=d×($x^k$-1)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/885159/783069 I didn't get this one I mean it's the opposite of my question there we supposed that n is prime and here we have to prove that n is prime

Answer (score 2):

If $x=1$, then clearly $n$ is prime. Let us consider $x>1$.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $n$ is composite. Then we may write $n=ab$ where $a,b\ge 2$. Thus

$$\begin{align*}1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}&=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{ab}-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^b-1)}{(x-1)}\\
&=\frac{(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}\dots+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}\\
&=(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}\dots+1)\end{align*}$$

which, provided $x>1$, is clearly composite. So we conclude that $n$ is in fact prime.