# An Olympiad math problem about prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $x,n ∈ \mathbb{N}$
 such that :

$1+x^1+x^2+x^3+\dots +x^{n-1}$ is prime .

Proof that $n$ is prime .

I actually suppose that $n$ isn't prime absurdly so $n=p×k$ such as $p$ is prime, I also use the $a^n-b^n$ formula .

Does anyone has another answer and can help ?

Comment: Hint: $x^n-1=x^{pk}-1=(x^p)^k-1^k$.

Comment: I think you have the simplest way, except no need to assume $ n = pk $ where $p$ is prime.  It's enough just to take any non-trivial factorisation $ n = ab $ where both $a,b > 1$.

Comment: The post is for questions and answers if you don't like it or you have nothing to add just keep your opinion for yourself and do a favor for yourself and people here ,you have to respect the people here who try to find out the answer and help other people you are a rude person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=1$, then clearly $n$ is prime. Let us consider $x>1$.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $n$ is composite. Then we may write $n=ab$ where $a,b\ge 2$. Thus

$$\begin{align*}1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}&=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{ab}-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^b-1)}{(x-1)}\\
&=\frac{(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}\dots+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}\\
&=(x^{b(a-1)}+x^{b(a-2)}+\dots+1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}\dots+1)\end{align*}$$

which, provided $x>1$, is clearly composite. So we conclude that $n$ is in fact prime.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot thank you

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as a few hours ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668108/an-olympiad-problem-in-prime-numbers-can-we-proof-that-n-is-prime-in-this-cas)?